# What's the best way to collect (Farm) equipment (weapons) in X-Com?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Sometimes, you are able to collect a weapon from an alien "without a scratch" on it, afterwards being able to use it in your unites without cost (when you have the technology to build it already, of course). The ways I know to collect alien weapons are the following:

- Kill an Alien while he is in your mind control.
- Stun an Alien and bring him with you.

But, what's the best way to collect (farm) those weapons? There are other ways, besides the two from above, to get weapons without cost?

Comment: I'd like to mention that obtaining at most 6 items that you will ever need can hardly be called "farming". You can't sell weapons, so unless you have that Second Wave option enabled, you don't "farm", you "get some".

Comment: @OrcJMR switching just the 6 plasma rifles across your 30+ operatives can be a major pain though.

Comment: @kotekzot exactly the "why" in my question

Comment: Is the effort of agonising over the best way to get a couple of extra weapons in stores really worth it to avoid sometimes swapping gear. Do you really want to fundamentally change your battle tactics (perhaps wasting a gear slot) to get the extra 'worthless' items so you can avoid the "major pain"?

Comment: @CraigYoung maybe... depend on the situation. Perhaps, at determinate situation, is the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a mind-controlled alien killed or stunning one are the only ways to get their weapons. Mind-controlled aliens dying impacts your squad's morale as if one of your operatives had died, which makes them more prone to panic and less successful at further psi attacks; while stunning aliens is risky, can only be done a limited number of times and requires the use of an equipment slot, but can be done much earlier than mind control. I tend to favor mind control, especially at the end of a mission, where the will penalty will be felt less.

Comment: Hmm, so, the MC have more pros than con? (this is what I understood) ?

Comment: I would say so, yes. Of course, you can only get the last alien's weapons by stunning it.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can only get the last alien's weapons by stunning it"?

Comment: You can't target mind-controlled aliens with regular weapons and explosives will destroy the weapon, right?

Comment: @MichelAyres - he likely means that if there is only one alien left and you MC him the mission immediately ends. Though I don't have MC yet so I can't personally testify to this. I prefer stunning after knocking an alien down to 1 health.

Comment: @Shaderach that doesn't happen. All aliens need to be dead or stunned for a mission to end.

Comment: I was understanding the same as @Shaderach , this is why I asked =) Now I get it, Since you need to kill all aliens to end the mission AND there is no way to kill "your" alien without blowing him into pieces, the only way to collect his weapon is by stunning.

Comment: @MichelAyres you can make other aliens kill MC'ed one

Comment: @SergeyGrinev I know, but if there is no other alien, it gets a little harder. But, do you have tips in doing this easier ?

Comment: Nop, for last alien standing there is only stun option.

Answer (score 4):

You could always combine the two approaches. Mind control, bring them close to a stunner, and stun them. This should mitigate any impact of moral loss, and overall be effective.

Comment: Really good point O.O!!